# How to update multiple rows with checked value and unchecked?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table structure like

```
  id | user_id | notification_id | is_email_opted | is_sms_opted
   1   88          10                 0               0
   1   88          12                 1               0
```

I have checkboxes like

```
<td><h6>Work Order</h6></td>
 <input type="checkbox" name="email_job" id="email_job">
         <input type="checkbox" name="work_order_email" id="work_order_email" checked disabled value="1"></label></td>     

               <input type="checkbox" name="work_order_sms" id="work_order_sms" value="1"></label></td>
                                </tr>
```

I have to update these values into table according to user_id and notification_id. ALready i am inserting notificaiton values default when user signup. Also when checkboxed checked i am storing it in hidden value and send the values to php

```
       <input type="hidden"  name="sms_job_notify" id="sms_job_notify" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" name="email_job_notify" id="email_job_notify" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="work_order_sms_notify" id="work_order_sms_notify" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="deal_email_notify" id="deal_email_notify" value="0">
```

I have tried with following php code to update it is working. the code is too complex

```
         if($email_job || $sms_job ){
            $update_data = array("is_email_opted"=>$email_job,"is_sms_opted"=>$sms_job);
            $this->db->where("notify_type_id",10);
            $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update("user_notification", $update_data);
            echo $this->db->last_query();
        }else{
            $update_data = array("is_email_opted"=>0,"is_sms_opted"=>0);
            $this->db->where("notify_type_id",10);
            $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update("user_notification", $update_data);
            echo $this->db->last_query();

        }

        if($work_order_sms ){
            $update_data = array("is_sms_opted"=>$work_order_sms);
            $this->db->where("notify_type_id",11);
            $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update("user_notification", $update_data);
            echo $this->db->last_query();
        }else{
            $update_data = array("is_sms_opted"=>0);
            $this->db->where("notify_type_id",11);
            $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update("user_notification", $update_data);
            echo $this->db->last_query();

        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post up the handling PHP code that you're using to process this form.

Comment: If it's working then what is the issue?

Comment: @epodax: i thought of reducing the code structure little bit but iwant to know is there any  way to do it

Comment: While I understand why you'd want to do so, a thing to keep in mind is that you need to have a fine balance between readability and code minimization, meaning that if you make the code "shorter/smaller" it might be harder to understand, which isn't a good thing.

Comment: @epodax: how to loop the checkboxes using select query like foreach($notification_type as $id) { echo "<input type="checkbox" name=$id> />